# how to upload and download files using amazon s3 grails plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, file-upload, amazon-s3, download

I'm using Amazon s3 grails plugin to upload a csv file on s3. Can i really upload csv file using this plugin?I'm trying this.Neither i'm getting any kind of error nor the file is getting uploaded.Plugin has no facility to download file from s3.Please tell how can i download?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using the plugin and instead importing the jets3t library into your project. Then you can do something like this:

```
String awsAccessKey = "YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY"
String awsSecretKey = "YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY"
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new AWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey)
S3Service s3Service = new RestS3Service(awsCredentials)

S3Bucket[] myBuckets = s3Service.listAllBuckets()
println "How many buckets to I have in S3? " + myBuckets.length
```

Take a look at this guide for more info:
http://www.jets3t.org/toolkit/code-samples.html

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a little late but I encounter this problem recently so thought of sharing it for future readers.

I am using Grails Version: 3.2.7 and [Grails AWS SDK S3 Plugin](https://github.com/agorapulse/grails-aws-sdk/tree/master/grails-aws-sdk-s3)

Here's my *UploadController*

```
class UploadController {

    def amazonS3Service
    def s3Bucket = 'YOUR-BUCKET-NAME'

    def index() {
        def multipartFile = request.getFile('file')

        if (multipartFile && !multipartFile.empty) {
            def fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()

            // push uploaded file to S3
            amazonS3Service.storeMultipartFile(s3Bucket, fileName, multipartFile)
            log.debug "written to s3"
        } else {
            log.debug "No file uploaded"
        }
        return
    }
}
```

to Download from s3, according to the documentation:

```
// Get a file
file = amazonS3Servuce.getFile('asset/foo/someKey.jpg', '/Users/ben/Desktop/photo.jpg')
```